# Retrieve a value of a specified line in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView that is displaying data stored in a file, normally, we can also delete a line (data) from this ListView. The file's datas are stored within another class. i want to retreive `value1`(public) variable of a specified line in the ListView before deleting it(please see code). Can i specify `value1` of `arg2` line of the ListView ?

```
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
int id) {
Carburant m= new Carburant(); //instanciate the class that contains the value1 variable
String value1= m.value1; //here i want to store value1 variable of arg2 line in the ListView
list.remove(arg2); //here all the line (data) will be deleted
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[listeView.getItem(index);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem%28int%29)

You can get the index from onClick.

Comment: any example please? It seems that it can solve the problem :\. It retreives all the datas in this line :))

Comment: You have to imlement OnItemClickListener, set it for your listView.addItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){void onItemClick...}) and so on. This will give you clicked item's id. you can then call listView.getItem(id) to retrieve the item from the listView.

Comment: look at this [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)